# Hadoop sorting for massive data

Tags: hadoop

Example: I have 100 servers, each has part of search index. When client makes a search I am using hadoop to go through these servers and select results. Results must be sorted.

The problem is that total amount of data output from each individual task is larger than memory (RAM and HDD) in server actually running the task - so I can not sort.

What is right way to get this problem solved?

And next question - I want to have pagination in search result - assuming huge amount of data - I can not use any cache...

thanks

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to answer. Maybe you could describe what you are doing in your map and reduce steps and which step is running out of memory? A description of what your data looks like might also be helpful.

Comment: this is pure theoretical question: what if reduce step gets to large amount of data?

Comment: Hadoop for search?Are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop sorts values associated with a key after map process is completed & before streaming the values to the reducer, through the OutputKeyComparatorClass. If you want to implement your own sorting algorithm, you need to write your own OutputKeyComparatorClass.

Comment: how would you pick key - assuming that input is large text file with one number per line (so result will be sorted one)

Comment: can you post a sample of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that Hadoop is designed for batch processing (think 18-wheeler not Maserati) so if this search has a constrained time limit to your users, Hadoop is not the right tool for the job.

That being said, Hadoop design strength is in distributed sorting (the magic that happens between the mapper and reducer) so if running out of memory is your concern, you want to organize your data in Key-Value pairs that allows the keys to be sorted by the distributed sort which is memory limited by the aggregate cluster memory and configuration.

Comment: yes, let hadoop sort the data by itself, or write your own method and override if you want to implement a customized sort